# How to properly mount folders inside a HDD in /mnt?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

I had 3 smaller disks on my machine, /dev/sda, /dev/sdb/ and /dev/sdc mounted respectively as /mnt/video, /mnt/audio and /mnt/media. Now I purchased a  WAY bigger drive and want to consolidate everything into one, but I already have so many services depending on those paths that modifying it would be a huge headache. I sucefully managed to rsync every disk to it's respective folder on the bigger drive mounted as /mnt/DATA01, currently the FSTAB is more or less like that:

```
UUID={devsdaUUID}       /mnt/video    ext4    defaults          0    2
UUID={devsdbUUID}       /mnt/audio    ext4    defaults          0    2
UUID={devsdcUUID}       /mnt/media    ext4    defaults          0    2
UUID={devsdeUUID}       /mnt/DATA01   ext4    defaults          0    2
```

I'm planning now to edit it to something like this to mount them on boot:

```
UUID={devsdeUUID}       /mnt/DATA01          ext4    defaults          0    2
/mnt/DATA01/video       /mnt/video           ext4    defaults          0    2
/mnt/DATA01/audio       /mnt/audio           ext4    defaults          0    2
/mnt/DATA01/media       /mnt/media           ext4    defaults          0    2
UUID={devsdaUUID}       /mnt/backup_video    ext4    defaults          0    2
UUID={devsdbUUID}       /mnt/backup_audio    ext4    defaults          0    2
UUID={devsdcUUID}       /mnt/backup_media    ext4    defaults          0    2
```

Is this approach correct? will it work properly or should I do something else instead to mount the folders like /mnt/DATA01/video into /mnt/video? like using bind instead of defaults or symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mount the three directories as ext4 since they aren't partitions, but you can use bind mounts like this:

```
UUID={devsdaUUID}       /mnt/backup_video    ext4    defaults          0    2
UUID={devsdbUUID}       /mnt/backup_audio    ext4    defaults          0    2
UUID={devsdcUUID}       /mnt/backup_media    ext4    defaults          0    2
UUID={devsdeUUID}       /mnt/DATA01          ext4    defaults          0    2
/mnt/DATA01/video       /mnt/video           none    bind              0    0
/mnt/DATA01/audio       /mnt/audio           none    bind              0    0
/mnt/DATA01/media       /mnt/media           none    bind              0    0
```